# Regarding different types of portal users

Tags: user, portal

Anyone can explain difference between  types of all portal users,what is its function?
such as
high volume standard Portal
customer community portal
customer community plus
etc....

Answer (score 0):

Communities are the latest and greatest.  Portals are legacy, but those licenses can be used for communities by customers who already owned them.

CC lets you have more users (millions) with a set of capabilities.  CC+ gives you sharing rules, reports/dashboards, approval process participation, and done other things, but only supports a few hundred thousand users, and cost more.

Feature comparison chart: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US